# Wordpress - trying to create shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I'm trying to do shortcode with default attributes.

Here's my code:

```
function custom_list_item_shortcode($attributes, $content = null ) {

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'icon' => '',
    'color' => ''
), $attributes ) );


$html = '<div class="listbox-item">';

//--If there is an icon show icon
if($icon != ''){
    $html .=  '<div class="listbox-icon"><i class="fa fa-'.$icon.' icon-'.$color.'"></i></div>';
}

$html .=  '<div class="listbox-content">'.$content.'</div>';
$html .= '</div>';
return  $html;
}
add_shortcode('icon-list', 'custom_list_item_shortcode');
```

What I want to achieve is that some things (for example font size etc.) are default and class is not displayed in firebug, but when someone wants to change font size, they can just type

```
[icon-list icon="globe" size="22"][/icon-list]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, you need to know how to set defaults to shortcodes? If so: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Alright, I've done everything as it's in documentation and it's still doesn't work. I'm desperate

Comment: Add `'size' => '22'` and implement the `size` attribute. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I know that I can do it, but then it shows as "unnamed class" if you don't include it in wp tymc editor. I want to have for example default size that you dont need to type in shortcode, but if admin wants to change it then types [icon-list size="50"] 
do you know what i mean?

Comment: I know what you want. You want to be able to call `[icon-list]` and `[icon-list size="30"]` and the first should use a default value. Post your updated code, with your attempt to solve this. Something must be wrong.

Comment: `function custom_list_item_shortcode($attributes, $content = null ) {

 $a = shortcode_atts( array(
  'icon' => '',
  'color' => '',
  'size' => '',
 ), $attributes  );


 $html = '<div class="listbox-item">';

 //--If there is an icon show icon
 if($a != ''){
  $html .=  "{$a['<div class="listbox-icon"><i class="fa fa-'.$icon.' icon-'.$color.'"></i></div>']}";
 }

 $html .=  '<div class="listbox-content">'.$content.'</div>';
 $html .= '</div>';
 return  $html;
}
add_shortcode('icon-list', 'custom_list_item_shortcode');`

I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Don't paste long codes in comments. Prefer to add an Edit section to the original question... About the code, you have no default values: they are all `'value' => ''`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want `size` to have a default value of `22`:

```
function custom_list_item_shortcode($attributes, $content = null ) {

  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      'icon' => '',
      'color' => '',
      'size' => '22'
  ), $attributes ) );    

  $html = '<div class="listbox-item" style="font-size:'.$size.'px">';

  //--If there is an icon show icon
  if($icon != ''){
      $html .=  '<div class="listbox-icon"><i class="fa fa-'.$icon.' icon-'.$color.'"></i></div>';
  }

  $html .=  '<div class="listbox-content">'.$content.'</div>';
  $html .= '</div>';
  return  $html;
}

add_shortcode('icon-list', 'custom_list_item_shortcode');
```

Read: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Sorry, im new to community.

Your code works as expected. Thank you sir +++